# Equity short Interest data source

Tags: equities, data, market-data, short-selling

I'm looking for short interest data (those disclosed on 15 days basis to FINRA)

- As far as I know FINRA publishes only OTC data (http://otce.finra.org/ESI).
- Nasdaq.com contains only nasdaq traded stocks (SI data of them)
- http://regsho.finra.org/regsho-Index.html is not what I'm looking for (short volume, not an interest)
- NYSE offers paid service containing it

Some sites like gurufocus.com (under ownership sections) contain it and I doubt they buy it from NYSE.

Do you know about feasible way to obtain this data (in CSV and free would be a dream, but I don't expect that), without scraping sites like gurufocus (some more official way like FINRA download page)

Comment: http://shortsqueeze.com/ is decent.  The monthly fee for membership is quite reasonable.

Comment: SunGard and DataExplorers were the two commercial products for this. Their historical coverage wasn't so great when I last checked years ago, but presumably is years better now.

Comment: shortsqueeze.com short interest data seems to be bi-weekly, correct?

Answer (score 2):

**FREE**

[Short Sale Data Source SEC](https://www.sec.gov/answers/shortsalevolume.htm)

[Data Reported to a FINRA TRF (NASDAQ TRF and NYX TRF)](http://www.finra.org/industry/trf/trf-regulation-sho-2016)

---

This is a direct link to all of the short sale data available.

[Short Sale Volume Data (NASDAQ TRF, NYX TRF, ADF and ORF)](http://regsho.finra.org/regsho-Index.html)
[image: Short Sale Volume and Transaction Data]

*PAID*

---

[Short Squeeze](http://shortsqueeze.com/historical_short_interest_data.php)
[image: Short Squeeze Homepage]

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? The question is specifically about short interest, not short volume.

Comment: Not sure if you can read, but just in case you cannot , the paid site lists short interest.  If you have a better answer, upload, otherwise kindly read more carefully =)

Answer (score 1):

The short interest data is available in WSJ, Barrons -

http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3062-shtnasdaq_A-listing.html

Company Symbol  8/31/18 8/15/18 Chg % Chg   % Float Days to
cover   Avg daily
volume
A V Homes, Inc. AVHI    1,495,223   1,612,125   -116,902    -7.3    14.0    12  127,240

The 1,495,223 is the short interest corresponding to 8/31.

Barrons has a similar URL -

Company Symbol  8/31/18 8/15/18 Chg % Chg   % Float Days to
cover   Avg daily
volume
D.R. Horton Inc.    DHI 11,153,948  10,699,837  454,111 4.2 3.3 4   2,887,108
Dana Incorporated   DAN 3,185,291.0 2,938,603.0 246,688 8.4 2.2 3   1,093,989
Danaher Corporation DHR 4,777,526   4,971,650   -194,124    -3.9    0.8 2   2,085,656

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever find what you're looking for? The only other place I could find was the COMPUSTAT database accessed via WRDS. You'd need to access this database through a business library though, and probably on-site.